# Python Improper Update of JSON string in sql

Tags: python, json, python-requests, pyodbc, reverse-geocoding

I'm doing reverse geocoding and updating the resultant O/P (which is in JSON format) and updating the sql table column with the json o/p, but it is unable to store or update it properly as expected.

Here is what it updates after doing reverse geocoding

`>pw`

`{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Nandanvan A Wing', 'short_name': 'Nandanvan A Wing', 'types': ['establishment', 'point_of_interest', 'premise']}, {'long_name': 'Shivaji Nagar Marg', 'short_name': 'Shivaji Nagar Marg', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Vishnu Prasad Society', 'short_name': 'Vishnu Prasad Society', 'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Navpada', 'short_name': 'Navpada', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_3']}, {'long_name': 'Parle Colony', 'short_name': 'Parle Colony', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_2']}, {'long_name': 'Vile ....72.8454698}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJ1SbMGMrJ5zsRQd3_uFHHDN4', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_3']}], 'status': 'OK'}`

But [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.108703,72.84742687) is what it actually is,

This is the code I used

```
import pyodbc          
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=test;PWD=test@321;autocommit=True')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select R_GEOCODE_ID, SOURCE_PXVAL, SOURCE_PYVAL from MST_NHB_R_GEOCODE where R_GEOCODE_ID=675421")
ID=[]
px_val=[]
py_val=[]

for row in cursor.fetchall():

      ID.append(row[0])
      px_val.append(row[1])
      py_val.append(row[2])
      #
      wp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}".format(row[1],row[2]))

      pw=wp.read().decode('utf-8')
      pw = json.loads(pw)

      if(pw['status'] == 'OK'):   
          sql = 'exec [db_name].dbo.USP_GEO_UPDATE ?, ?'
          values = (str(pw), row[0])
          cursor.execute(sql, (values))



cnxn.commit()      
cursor.close()      
cnxn.close()
```

It is converting the JSON entirely into `'` quote instead while reverse geocoding it is in `"` quotes.
Any suggestions on this will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: `pw = json.loads(pw)` is converting the json response into a python dict object, so you'll no longer have valid json. Try `values = (json.dumps(pw), row[0])`

Comment: ohh gosh!!! it worked, I was converting it to string because without that it was giving an error, "that its not a string", so I parsed it into `str()`, Thank you !!!. could you please convert it into an answer so that I can upvote it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `pw = json.loads(pw)`, you create a python dictionary object from the JSON response. When you then call `str()` on that object, you'll get the string representation of the Python dict, not valid JSON. Instead, use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) to create a JSON-formatted string. So, `values = (json.dumps(pw), row[0])`. The trailing "s" in `dumps` and `loads` indicates "string".